# LARAVEL ROUTES not accept

Tags: laravel, routes

[image]

and it works:
[image]

---

im add route and have view:
[image]
and errors:
[image]

wtf??? only copy paste, and rename...

Comment: Upload code not screenshots of your code, nobody will help you if you yourself are not even dedicated enough to put some time into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `layouts/app.blade.php` There's something like `route('qwe')` and this route doesn't exist at all. So delete it from the layout and it should work.

#### Update

You're calling `route('kwe')` but you didn't name the route in the file. so add a name method to your route like the following.

```
Route::get('kwe', function(){
    return view('kwe');
})->name('kwe');
```

#### Update 2

`route` helper's parameter is the route name not its path. So you need to name the route before calling it using `route` helper.

If you wanna use the path itself instead you can use `url` helper.

Comment: <li><a href="{{route('qwe')}}">Занести товар</a></li>

Comment: ah, I see that you have this route
I'll update my answer

Comment: yes it works, but why? previous route not needed name

Comment: im not understend 1 questons, why not need name for "client route"

Comment: Sir, I explained in my answer that `route` helper needs the route name not its path.